# I want to give a extension method that return font of Int, It's right?

Tags: ios, swift

Can I give a Int method that generate UIFont?

```
extension Int {
    var font: UIFont {
        return UIFont.fitMediumFont(size: CGFloat(self))
    }
}
```

use it:

```
label.font = 16.font
```

My partner don't like this. But I think this API is more convenient and readable. I'm confused.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackOverFlow, an int which return a Font is too confuse to be used, or implemented to say least, another thing is if you need to use another font type of size 16 how you would implement it?

Comment: Hey and welcome! I use such API for instantiating `TimeInterval`s. Like `16.minutes` or `2.hours`. But instantiating `UIKit` object from a `Foundation` value is really confusing.

Comment: why don't you do it in the other way, use UIFont extension with static (class) func then use it like UIFont(16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it other way

```
extension UIFont {
    class func size(_ size: Int) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(size))
    }
}
```

then use it like

```
let font = UIFont.size(16)
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I want. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

why don't you make and extension of UIFont? Here an example of extension for Work Sans Light font

```
extension UIFont {

    /// Font Work Sans Light
    ///
    /// - Parameter size: Font size you need
    /// - Returns: your custom font for custom size
    class func WorkSansLight(ofSize size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: "WorkSans-Light", size: size)!
    }
}
```

When you are going to use it you can call it specifying the font size you need:

```
label.font = UIFont.WorkSansLight(ofSize: 13.0)
```

Answer (score 5):

This will be helpful if you are using a family of fonts, like in my case **OpenSans Fonts**

```
struct AppFont {
enum FontType: String {
    case Bold = "OpenSans-Bold"
    case Regular = "OpenSans"
    case BoldItalic = "OpenSans-BoldItalic"
    case ExtraBoldItalic = "OpenSans-ExtraboldItalic"
    case Italic = "OpenSans-Italic"
    case Light = "OpenSans-Light"
    case LightItalic = "OpenSansLight-Italic"
    case SemiBold = "SemiBold"
    case SemiBoldItalic = "SemiBoldItalic"
}   
static func font(type: FontType, size: CGFloat) -> UIFont{
    return UIFont(name: type.rawValue, size: size)!
}
}
```

Use:
`myLabel.font = AppFont.font(type: .Bold, size: 18.0)`